# arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc error: selected processor does not support `vrev64.32 d31,d0' in Thumb mode when compiling Onion OS

Tags: gcc

When attempting to compile the source code for Onion OS, getting the following error.  The manufacturer does not accept user submitted issues in github.  There is also no info on manufacturer web site for any info on this error.

https://github.com/OnionUI/Onion

```
git clone https://github.com/OnionUI/Onion.git
cd Onion/
git checkout -b v4.1.0
make git-submodules
make
```

And the output of the make command:

```
make[1]: Entering directory '/root/workspace/Onion/src/clock'
-e make[clock]: Building font/font_drawing.c
-e > /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -I../../include -I../common -DPLATFORM_LINUX -Wall -I./font -Os -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -std=gnu18 -c font/font_drawing.c -o font/font_drawing.o
-e make[clock]: Building stringPrinting.c
-e > /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -I../../include -I../common -DPLATFORM_LINUX -Wall -I./font -Os -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -std=gnu18 -c stringPrinting.c -o stringPrinting.o
-e make[clock]: Building main.c
-e > /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -I../../include -I../common -DPLATFORM_LINUX -Wall -I./font -Os -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -std=gnu18 -c main.c -o main.o
-e make[clock]: Building gfx.c
-e > /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -I../../include -I../common -DPLATFORM_LINUX -Wall -I./font -Os -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -std=gnu18 -c gfx.c -o gfx.o/tmp/ccBtXD0N.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/ccBtXD0N.s:1747: Error: selected processor does not support `vrev64.32 d31,d0' in Thumb mode
/tmp/ccBtXD0N.s:1747: Error: selected processor does not support `vrev64.32 d30,d1' in Thumb mode
/tmp/ccBtXD0N.s:1747: Error: selected processor does not support `vrev64.32 d29,d2' in Thumb mode
/tmp/ccBtXD0N.s:1747: Error: selected processor does not support `vrev64.32 d28,d3' in Thumb mode
/tmp/ccBtXD0N.s:1747: Error: selected processor does not support `vrev64.32 d27,d4' in Thumb mode
/tmp/ccBtXD0N.s:1747: Error: selected processor does not support `vrev64.32 d26,d5' in Thumb mode
/tmp/ccBtXD0N.s:1747: Error: selected processor does not support `vrev64.32 d25,d6' in Thumb mode
/tmp/ccBtXD0N.s:1747: Error: selected processor does not support `vrev64.32 d24,d7' in Thumb mode
/tmp/ccBtXD0N.s:1747: Error: selected processor does not support `vrev64.32 d23,d8' in Thumb mode
/tmp/ccBtXD0N.s:1747: Error: selected processor does not support `vrev64.32 d22,d9' in Thumb mode
/tmp/ccBtXD0N.s:1747: Error: selected processor does not support `vrev64.32 d21,d10' in Thumb mode
/tmp/ccBtXD0N.s:1747: Error: selected processor does not support `vrev64.32 d20,d11' in Thumb mode
/tmp/ccBtXD0N.s:1747: Error: selected processor does not support `vrev64.32 d19,d12' in Thumb mode
/tmp/ccBtXD0N.s:1747: Error: selected processor does not support `vrev64.32 d18,d13' in Thumb mode
/tmp/ccBtXD0N.s:1747: Error: selected processor does not support `vrev64.32 d17,d14' in Thumb mode
/tmp/ccBtXD0N.s:1747: Error: selected processor does not support `vrev64.32 d16,d15' in Thumb mode
/tmp/ccBtXD0N.s:1747: Error: VFP single precision register expected -- `vstmdb r2!,{q8-q15}'
/tmp/ccBtXD0N.s:1747: Error: selected processor does not support `vrev64.32 d31,d0' in Thumb mode
/tmp/ccBtXD0N.s:1747: Error: selected processor does not support `vrev64.32 d30,d1' in Thumb mode
/tmp/ccBtXD0N.s:1747: Error: selected processor does not support `vrev64.32 d29,d2' in Thumb mode
/tmp/ccBtXD0N.s:1747: Error: selected processor does not support `vrev64.32 d28,d3' in Thumb mode
/tmp/ccBtXD0N.s:1747: Error: selected processor does not support `vrev64.32 d27,d4' in Thumb mode
/tmp/ccBtXD0N.s:1747: Error: selected processor does not support `vrev64.32 d26,d5' in Thumb mode
/tmp/ccBtXD0N.s:1747: Error: selected processor does not support `vrev64.32 d25,d6' in Thumb mode
/tmp/ccBtXD0N.s:1747: Error: selected processor does not support `vrev64.32 d24,d7' in Thumb mode
/tmp/ccBtXD0N.s:1747: Error: selected processor does not support `vrev64.32 d23,d8' in Thumb mode
/tmp/ccBtXD0N.s:1747: Error: selected processor does not support `vrev64.32 d22,d9' in Thumb mode
/tmp/ccBtXD0N.s:1747: Error: selected processor does not support `vrev64.32 d21,d10' in Thumb mode
/tmp/ccBtXD0N.s:1747: Error: selected processor does not support `vrev64.32 d20,d11' in Thumb mode
/tmp/ccBtXD0N.s:1747: Error: selected processor does not support `vrev64.32 d19,d12' in Thumb mode
/tmp/ccBtXD0N.s:1747: Error: selected processor does not support `vrev64.32 d18,d13' in Thumb mode
/tmp/ccBtXD0N.s:1747: Error: selected processor does not support `vrev64.32 d17,d14' in Thumb mode
/tmp/ccBtXD0N.s:1747: Error: selected processor does not support `vrev64.32 d16,d15' in Thumb mode
```